# Isomorphism matrix problem

Tags: linear-algebra

So the question asks:

Recall that  $U^{2\times 2}$ is the vector space of 2X2 upper triangular matrices. Which of the following functions are isomorphisms?

A. The function T: $U^{2\times 2}$ to $P_2$ given by $T(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\ 0&c\end{bmatrix})=(a+b)+ct+(a+b)t^2.$

B. The function T:$ℂ$→$ℝ_2$ given by $T(a+bi)=\begin{bmatrix}a\\ a+b\end{bmatrix}$

C. The function T: $U^{2\times 2}$ to $P_2$ given by $T(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\ 0&c\end{bmatrix})=a+bc t+ bt^2.$

D.  The function T:$ℝ_3$→$P_3$ given by $T(\begin{bmatrix}a\\ b\\ c\end{bmatrix})= at+bt^2+ct^3.$

So according to the definition of isomorphism: An isomorphism of vector spaces is a bijective (or invertible) linear transformation. Vector spaces V and W are isomorphic if there exists an isomorphism V−→ W.

I thought the answer would be CD, because

In A, $T(\begin{bmatrix}4&2\\ 0&3\end{bmatrix})=(\begin{bmatrix}3&3\\ 0&3\end{bmatrix})=6+3t+6t^2.$ While for B, I just do not think it is right.

Is my answer right? And is there any easy way to check if a matrix is isomorphism or not?

Comment: please do not delete you question to create it again soon afterwords. People could be working on your problem while you delete the question. Thanks

Comment: You need to express these linear maps (indeed all of them are linear) with respect to some pair of bases (you need to choose these in each case) of the source and destination vector spaces. Then, $T$ is an isomorphism if and only if that matrix is invertible.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Actually the map in (C) is not linear.

Comment: @Kior:  Your reasoning for (A) is sound: since $T$ is not bijective, it cannot be an isomorphism.  For (B), you cannot argue based on thinking that something is or is not right.  You need to check each part of the definition of an isomorphism.  Is $T$ a linear transformation?  Is $T$ bijective?  Similarly, for (C) and (D), you must verify the conditions.  You should not consider any answer you come up with to be "right" unless you have a well-reasoned argument in support of your conclusion.

Comment: @MichaelJoyce: You are right, I overlooked the term $bct$ (or rather misread it as $bt$). So (C) cannot be an isomorphism, for already failing to be linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way?

You need to check this and only this condition.

First of all, the transformation law must be linear (as @Michael Joyce just remembered). So $C$ is not an isomorphism.

Secondly, domain and codomain must have the same dimension. So how D could be an isomorphism? $\mathrm{dim}(\mathbb{R^3}) = 3$ while $\mathrm{dim}(P^3) = 4$. For $A$ and $B$ such condition holds true.

Finally, the image must be the whole codomain.
The image of $A$ has dimension 2 while its codomain 3. So image and codomain are different. $A$ is not an isomorphism.

As to $B$...
When one talks about an isomorphism of a linear space must always specify the field. For such an isomorphism to be of any sense the field that can be taken into consideration must be a subspace (proper or improper) of the fields of linear spaces of its domain and codomain.

For $B$ the domain is a linear space over $\mathbb{C}$ and also is a linear space over subfields of $\mathbb{C}$. The maximum (in the sense of inclusion) field that can be chosen over which domain and codomain can be defined as linear space is $\mathbb{R}$. So you can verify if $C$ is an isomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$-linear space.

The second condition holds true, because the dimension of $\mathbb{C}$ as an $\mathbb{R}$-linear space is 2 the same as that of its codomain.

The last condition holds true as well, because the image and the codomain are equal.

Comment: Great answer. However, I do have one question. Can you clarify why $\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{im}(T)) = 2$ for subproblem A?

Comment: I am unsure how the basis for the image of $T$ is constructed.